# my SDHC card slot has stopped working in win8.1. Any solutions?

Tags: windows-8.1, all-in-one

previously in win7 it was working fine. but after upgrading to win8.1 it stopped working.
my PC is 
HP All-in-one 
Atholn II X2
3GB RAM 
win8.1 64-bit

tried installing various drivers. But card is not getting detected...
Help please

Comment: Have you tried other cards?  Have you run trouble shooting diagnostics?

Comment: The card isn't being mounted or the device isn't being mounted.  Because you installing drivers would only help the device function.  A malfunctioning card wouldn't stop malfunctioning with a different device driver for the reader.  **It sounds like a problem with the SDHC memory card itself.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SD reader is detected by the system? Try to Update the Windows if yes. If that doesn't help UNINSTALL reader drivers (all) and then try update again. 
If above didn't help make sure you have correct drivers. Best to do that is to look on HP driver site for your system.

If still have problems try to Run the Hardware troubleshooter and check:

1. press Windows key + C on your keyboard for the Charms bar,
2. type Troubleshooting and then click Troubleshooting under Settings,
3. now type Hardware Troubleshooter in the search option,
4. Click on Hardware troubleshooter to run the troubleshooter.

If that doesn't work try following:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/windows-update-error-0x800f081f